# Is it ok to mark EOL questions as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, end-of-life

I understand discussions about EOL releases here on meta are getting abundant, sorry about that.

But this question was inspired by this one: [Cant boot from windows 8 after installing Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/412981/)

What I did, was leave a comment about EOL releases (using [Pro-forma comments script](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/)), but instead of flagging the question to be closed for being about an EOL release, I flagged it as a duplicate to [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/).

Was that the right way to go? Or should I have just flagged it for "EOL closure".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, I think that's fine. You've done what I would.

And I think this is preferred (opposed to closing OT and telling them about the duplicate) because the system *handles* the duplicate in a different way. It should serve to better push people from Google et al to the right place.