# How to decide which flag is the correct one?

Tags: support

This days I found some questions about to install software in no longer supported releases (linke xenial)

I never know for sure flagging as EOL or flagging as a duplicate (like how to install or upgrade from a no longer supported release) ?

Comment: Maybe not all the time, but I would say if a duplicate exists it's more valuable to use the dupe flag. I asked a similar question quite a while ago in case that helps https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8219/is-it-ok-to-mark-eol-questions-as-duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**Note:** Opinions ahead)

A general rule of thumb I have when trying to decide is to look at how much work went into the question:

| Effort | Action |
| --- | --- |
| Two sentences and calling the OS "Obonto 12" | Flag as EOL |
| A paragraph with no stated attempt to solve the issue | Link to possible answer (no flagging until later) |
| A paragraph and maybe an "I tried everything online" | Ask follow-up question(s) and include an emoji |
| A series of paragraphs clearly outlining the goal, the issue(s), what's been tried, and the results | Link to possible answer(s), ask follow-up questions, offer solutions (regardless of EOL status), or some combination of the above. |

That said, I will admit there are times when I have no idea how to classify something and just leave it for the rest of the community. If I hit the review queues while in a sour mood, a hastily-crafted two-sentence "Obonto" question may result in language so foul an East Coast rapper would blush ... which doesn't help anybody.